# Proof of Bienayme Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

I have a bit of trouble about the proof of Bienayme Inequality.

Bienayme Inequality is as follows:
If X has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{|X-\mu|}{\sigma}\ge k\right)\le\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Bienayme's Proof:
Let $B = \{|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma\}$ and $\mathbb{1}_B$ be the indicator random variable. Then $(X-\mu)^2\mathbb{1}_B\ge\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{1}_B$ and $\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{1}_B)=\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{P}(B)$, hence
$$\sigma^2=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]$$
$$\ge\mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^2\mathbb{1_B})$$
$$\ge\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{1}_B)$$
$$=\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B)$$
$$=\sigma^2k^2\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{B}).$$

There is only one thing that I don't understand:
Why is $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]\ge \mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^2\mathbb{1_B})$. How can we explain /derive that?
Many different explanations and interpretations are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1_B$ is an indicator random variable. It can take ane of two values, $0$ or $1$. So for any non-negative random variable $X$ we have $X1_B \leq X$ with probability one.

Therefore $E(X1_B)\leq E(X)$ for every non-negative random variable $X$ and every event $E$.

Comment: for any/every random variable X >> for any/every **nonnegative** random variable X.